# from flask_mysqldb import MySQL gives import error : ImportError: No module named flask_mysqldb

Tags: python, mysql

I use ubuntu 16.04, My python version is 2.7.12 and I tried every installation but i still get flask_mysqldb import error when i try to run the above command.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "app.py", line 3, in <module>
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
ImportError: No module named flask_mysqldb
```

MySQL is install in my system. I am able to work independently as mysql  but not able to remove the above import error.

Someone please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to install it first. It's not packaged in Ubuntu repositories, so you'll have to use `pip2`.

```
pip2 install flask-mysqldb
```

or if you want to install it systemwide

```
sudo pip2 install flask-mysqldb
```

Further documentation is provided by [the project itself](https://flask-mysqldb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked but i couldn't upvote, please upvote my question. I tried the same using pip and pip3 but it was still giving me import error. since pip corresponds to python2 version why i was not able to do it initially.

Comment: Do i always have to use pip2 install ... for any installation since my python version is 2.7.12? @vidarlo

Comment: It's the safest. You're guaranteed that `pip2` will always be for python2.

Comment: OK thanks @vidarlo. i spend a week over this using pip and pip3, none of the work. Thanks a lot to you . : )

Answer (score 0):

for linux you have to install library for python mysql client 
if you are in linux run a sudo

```
sudo apt-get install python3.6-dev libmysqlclient-dev
```

note you have to modify your paython version in above command